# このエラーを修正するにはどうすればよいですか？ TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python3, gps

私は現在gpsモジュールを使用しており、緯度と経度のデータを抽出したいと考えています。 しかし、プログラムを実行すると、最初は問題ないように見えますが、ある時点で停止し、このエラーが表示されます。

これが私のプログラムです。

```
stream = Serial('com5', 9600)
t1 = time.time()

while True:
    ubr = UBXReader(stream)
    (raw_data, parsed_data) = ubr.read()

    #extract latitude and longitude data from parsed data
    if str(raw_data[0:6]) == "b'$GNRMC'":
        
        lat = parsed_data.lat
        lon = parsed_data.lon
        
        #declare latitude and longitude into string
        gps1 = str(lat)
        gps2 = str(lon)
    
    #measure finish time
    t2 = time.time()        
    elapsed_time = t2 - t1
    print(elapsed_time, gps1, gps2)
    
    #measure the time data every 100ms
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: 別の考え方として、こうした併せて利用することを掲げているライブラリを使ってみるのはどうでしょう？ [pynmeagps 1.0.8](https://pypi.org/project/pynmeagps/) `There is a companion library pyubx2, which handles u-blox ™ UBX © protocol GNSS/GPS messages.`

Answer (score 1):

スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！
エラーが何行目で発生しているかがお手元ではわかるかと思いますが、
コードを拝見する限り、リストを正常に取得できず、
リストのスライスをとる箇所でエラーが発生してしまっていると考えられます。

主な原因としてはubr.read()の実行頻度が高くなってしまい、シリアルポートにデータが入りきっていないことで、おそらくリストを取得できていないかと思われます。リストが正常に取得できているかを確認するif文をraw_dataの取得直後に加えて、異常であれば以降の処理をスキップしてsleepすれば解決すると思います。

```python
stream = Serial('com5', 9600)
t1 = time.time()

while True:
    ubr = UBXReader(stream)
    # ここでraw_dataが正常に取得できていない
    (raw_data, parsed_data) = ubr.read()

    #extract latitude and longitude data from parsed data
    # おそらくここでエラーが発生している
    if str(raw_data[0:6]) == "b'$GNRMC'":
        
        lat = parsed_data.lat
        lon = parsed_data.lon
        
        #declare latitude and longitude into string
        gps1 = str(lat)
        gps2 = str(lon)
    
    #measure finish time
    t2 = time.time()        
    elapsed_time = t2 - t1
    print(elapsed_time, gps1, gps2)
    
    #measure the time data every 100ms
    time.sleep(0.1)
```